# How to connect a mesh using gmsh and vtk in python

Tags: python, mesh, vtk, finite-element-analysis, gmsh

I'm working on a project that creates and manipulates meshes on geometric objects using the finite element method. So far, the user imports a file (.step) and selects areas of the object to create meshes. I'm using the gmsh API and the VTK interface for the software.

```
componentSelected.meshGeometry.append(filter.GetOutput())  # Add the polygon junction object to the component's mesh geometry list
writer = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()  # Create the STL file writing object
writer.SetInputData(filter.GetOutput())  # Set the polygon junction object as the STL file writing object
writer.SetFileName("grid.stl")  # Set the output file name as "grid.stl"
writer.Write()  # Write the output file
gmsh.initialize()  # Initialize Gmsh
gmsh.merge("grid.stl")  # Import the mesh file
gmsh.model.mesh.create_edges()  # Create mesh edges
gmsh.model.mesh.create_faces()  # Create mesh faces
gmsh.model.mesh.create_topology()  # Create mesh topology
gmsh.model.mesh.create_geometry()  # Create mesh geometry
# gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(1, [1], 1)  # Define physical group 1 as polygon 1
# gmsh.model.geo.add_curve_loop([1], 1)  # Define curve loop 1 as curve 2
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()  # Synchronize geometry
gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()  # Synchronize geometry
if meshType == 6:
    # If the mesh type is triangular
    gmsh.option.set_number('Mesh.Algorithm', meshType)  # Set the mesh type to triangular
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.MeshSizeMin', 0)  # Set the minimum mesh size
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.MeshSizeMax', 1)  # Set the maximum mesh size
elif meshType == 8:
    # If the mesh type is quadrangular
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.Algorithm', meshType)  # Set the mesh type to quadrangular
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.MeshSizeMin', 0)  # Set the minimum mesh size
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.MeshSizeMax', 1)  # Set the maximum mesh size
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.RecombineAll', 1)  # Set recombination of all meshes to true
    gmsh.option.setNumber('Mesh.RecombinationAlgorithm', 3)  # Set the mesh recombination algorithm to "blossom full-quad"
    gmsh.option.setNumber("Mesh.SubdivisionAlgorithm", 1)  # Set the mesh subdivision algorithm to "all quadrangles"
gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()  # Synchronize geometry
gmsh.model.mesh.generate(2)  # Generate the mesh
gmsh.write("mesh.vtk")  # Write the mesh in VTK format
gmsh.finalize()  # Finalize Gmsh

reader = vtk.vtkDataSetReader()  # Create the VTK file reading object
reader.SetFileName("mesh.vtk")  # Set the input file name as "mesh.vtk"
reader.Update()  # Update the VTK file reading object
grid = reader.GetOutput()  # Set the VTK file reading object as the mesh object
filter = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridGeometryFilter()  # Create the unstructured mesh geometry filtering object
filter.SetInputData(grid)  # Set the mesh object as the unstructured mesh geometry filtering object
filter.Update()  # Update the unstructured mesh geometry filtering object
edges = vtk.vtkExtractEdges()  # Create the edges extraction object
edges.SetInputConnection(filter.GetOutputPort())  # Set the unstructured mesh geometry filtering object as the edges extraction object
edges.Update()  # Update the edges extraction object
try:
    componentSelected.meshGeometry[main.selectedId] = grid  # Set the mesh object as the component's mesh geometry
    mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()  # Create the mesh data mapping object
    mapper.SetInputData(edges.GetOutput())  # Set the edges extraction object as the mesh data mapping object
    mapper2 = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()  # Create the mesh data mapping object
    mapper2.SetInputData(grid)  # Set the mesh object as the mesh data mapping object
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()  # Create the actor object
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)  # Set the mesh data mapping object as the actor object
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 0)  # Set the color of the actor object to black
    actor.GetProperty().SetInterpolationToFlat()
    actor.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn()  # Set the visibility of the actor's edges to true
    actor2 = vtk.vtkActor()  # Create the actor object
    actor2.SetMapper(mapper2)  # Set the mesh data mapping object as the actor object
    actor2.GetProperty().SetInterpolationToFlat()
    actor2.GetProperty().SetColor(componentSelected.redColor, componentSelected.greenColor, componentSelected.blueColor)  # Set the color of the actor object to the component's color
    componentSelected.meshActor.append(actor)  # Add the actor object to the list of component mesh actors
    componentSelected.geometryMeshActor.append(actor2)  # Add the actor object to the list of component geometry mesh actors
    main.ren.AddActor(actor)  # Add the actor object to the scene
    main.componentId = None  # Set the component identifier to null
    main.selectedId += 1  # Increment the selection identifier
    # Add the mesh to the scene
    for actor in componentSelected.meshActor:
        main.ren.AddActor(actor)
    main.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().Render()
    main.selectedComponents.clear()  # Clear the list of selected components
    main.selectedCells.clear()  # Clear the list of selected cells
    return
except Exception as error:
    # If the mesh is not generated
    message = QtGui.QMessageBox()
    message.setText(f"error: {error}")
    message.exec()
    return
```

[unconnected meshes in a .step extractor fan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACmoX.png)

Answer (score -1):

To connect a mesh using Gmsh and visualize it using VTK in Python, you can use the `pygmsh` library to generate the mesh with Gmsh and then use `pyvista` or `vtk` to visualize it.

First, make sure you have `pygmsh`, `pyvista`, and `vtk` installed in your Python environment. You can install them using pip:

```bash
pip install pygmsh pyvista vtk
```

Here's an example of how you can generate a simple mesh with Gmsh and visualize it using VTK:

```py
import pygmsh
import pyvista as pv

# Create a function to define a simple mesh using pygmsh
def create_mesh():
    geom = pygmsh.built_in.Geometry()

    # Define a circle
    geom.add_circle([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 1.0)

    # Generate the mesh
    mesh = pygmsh.generate_mesh(geom)
    return mesh

# Create the mesh using pygmsh
mesh = create_mesh()

# Extract points and cells from the mesh
points = mesh.points
cells = mesh.cells_dict["triangle"]

# Create a PyVista mesh from the points and cells
pv_mesh = pv.PolyData(points, cells)

# Create a plotter and visualize the mesh
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pv_mesh, show_edges=True)
plotter.show()
```

This example generates a simple circular mesh using Gmsh through `pygmsh`, extracts the points and cells from the generated mesh, and then creates a `pyvista` mesh (`pv.PolyData`) using those points and cells. Finally, it uses `pyvista` to visualize the mesh.

You can modify the geometry and mesh generation process in the `create_mesh` function according to your specific requirements. The `pygmsh` library offers various geometric primitives and methods to create complex geometries.

Remember to adjust the mesh generation and visualization process as needed based on your specific mesh requirements and geometry.